# How to check to see whether you have been kicked from the Shared Document - Desperate

Tags: vba, connection, shared

How would I check if I'm still connected to the Shared document? Upon Close, my file needs to SaveAs (overrides the most recent version), which causes big problems if a person was kicked from the document (happens when unsharing the document to make essential changes).

I therefore need to stop the Sub from running when someone has been kicked from the document (not the same as having a manually unshared document) and he closes it a week later after forgetting he left it open by mistake. This is because all the data which has been entered in the meanwhile is lost.

Here's what is needed;

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

'Other Commands run here incuding Protecting the sheets/workbook ect.

'Here I need an If statement Which terminates the Sub if the user has been disconnected (kicked) from the document.
'(It should not happen if ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing = False)
'(I'll add a message box to explain circumstances if this is the case)
'(I might need to prevent the person from saving the workbook altogether (to prevent the document to be overwritten)

If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing = False Then
    Call SaveAsShared 'Saves the workbook as shared (overrides)
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Save 'Only saves as normal when the document was shared upon close (but defaults the current document name (which will override when no attention is paid))
End If

End Sub
```

Any Help Will be much appreciated!